# Unrecognized selector sent to instance on click

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, button

Everytime I run my app and click my facebook log in button it crashes due to error:

```
##Error 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController facebookbutton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fce2b700360'
```

My view controller has a button(facebookbutton) which is suppose to open up the facebook log in url.

```
##My code for the button
@IBAction func facebookbutton(_ sender: Any) {
    FBSDKLoginManager().logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email", "public_profile"], from: self) {
        (loginResult: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult?, error: Error?) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Custom FB Login Failed:", error!)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

The error pops up in app delegate
[image]

I've tried searching if i messed up the outlets and even tried making a new button. I'm still getting the error. Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely forgot to set your custom view controller class to match the one you created in the storyboard.  I’ve attached a screen shot to help you out.  Replace where it says ‘MyViewControler’ with whatever your view controllers class is that contains the method `facebookButton`

[image]

Comment: Somehow you were right, I added a space between the custom class name before. You just saved me hours over a silly mistake I appreciate that so much. Thank you :)